# Add sdp service record to Toshiba Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to add a custom rfcomm service record into the database but it always comes back with error code -2008 ("Invalied service record data into SDP-DB(possibility to be broken").

I haven't had this problem with other API's such as widcomm, bluesoliel, MS-stack. Probably, there is some error in the definition of service attributes.

Code snippet:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3973099/code.txt

Any help appreciated,

Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line from:

```
0x36, 0x00, 0x69,
```

to

```
0x36, 0x00, 0x66,
```

The length value there is wrong. :-)

(Or to

```
0x35, 0x66,
```

)

Also I would expect that adding the ServiceRecordHandle attribute is wrong as I would presume that the stack has to add that -- the user can't tell what handles are already in use.

Comment: Sorry, for a really LATE reply :) You were absolutely correct. Thanks!